# How to measure the color of a screen (in HEX)?

Tags: colors, measurement

I'm developing a new advanced review website for all kind of devices. And for that, I want to measure the accuracy of colors from displays (for example a smartphone or a normal screen). I already have a built-in system to calculate the delta e of two colors.

My plan is to display some standard test colors patches at the screen (where I already know the color HEX code) and then compare this to some kind of color measurement. The problem is I need a device which can measure this color from a screen (something glowing...) but normal color meters aren't designed for that. Such a device must exist because [notebookcheck](https://www.notebookcheck.net) actually do this somehow - but I have no idea what they use.

So my question what devices do I need for that purpose? Also if this isn't the right place to ask I'm sorry for that.

**The device requirements are:**

- Should give me HEX color codes
- Also more like 2019 tech with a nice interface (app) if possible

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Unfortunately, hardware shopping suggestion questions like this are off-topic for this site. We do have a https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ site though, which should be able to help you out.

Comment: Ok sry for that, I will consider this in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopping requests are off-topic here, but you're after a "*colorimeter*".

When it comes to measuring a display's ability to represent color, you're not likely to get "*hex codes*" back, at least not in the way that you're thinking (due to the sensor's dynamic range and potential for saturation that needs to be avoided).

For example, displaying `#00FF00` (pure / bright green in 24-bit color) will not likely result in a simple output value of `#00FF00` from the tool, because if the display is *too bright* there is no way to represent this fact - you've run out of dynamic range. A tool *could* provide this value against a gamut, but there will need to be other information alongside to indicate artefacts that cannot be accurately represented in 24-bits alone.

Another aspect (as touched on in the Eizo page linked below) - what happens if a display renders "*green*" at a wavelength that is not the agreed upon wavelength? This cannot be accurately represented with 24-bit color.

This is also emphasised by the fact that many consumer displays (e.g: smart phones) produce massively over-saturated images, along with the incoming trend for consumer displays to support HDR, with 10-bit or 12-bit color.

There are a large number of things that will make simply displaying "*test patches*" awkward and likely invalid.

These devices (and their accompanying software) will provide you with information on the display's ability to render a [gamut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamut) - for example a coverage of 97% of [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) is quite reasonable for modern consumer displays, with high end displays targeted at professional use (aka "*wide gamut*") achieving good coverage of [Adobe RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_RGB_color_space).

[image: Gamut Plots]

Without meaning to be rude, I'd suggest you read up on the topic before turning your hand to writing reviews - Eizo have a decent write up: [*The Ability to Display Color Correctly Is Vital: Understanding the Color Gamut of an LCD Monitor*](https://www.eizoglobal.com/library/basics/lcd_monitor_color_gamut/index.html)

With [ΔE*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) you should understand that the complexities of human color vision also play their role... for example we are far more [sensitive to some wavelengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision) (green) than others (blue / red), and this must be accounted for in the model.

[image: Human Color Sensitivity]

Comment: *"you're not going to be getting "hex codes" back"* -- Not an accurate statement.  I've used colorimeter software that provided the RGB measurement as a hexadecimal triplet.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your effort! About the color patches: in photography, you have such test charts with certain color patches for quality checking - therefore my thought was to do the same on a screen (). But it's seems to be way more complex than that

Comment: @sawdust - thanks, I've expanded on what I meant somewhat... I hope that resolves it, if not please let me know.